# LiveData binding observer being registered multiple times when changing device orientation even when using viewLifeCycleOwner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I have a view model that is data binded to a fragment. The view model is shared with the main activity.

I've button is binded to the view as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/startStopBtn"
    android:text="@{dashboardViewModel.startStopText == null ? @string/startBtn : dashboardViewModel.startStopText}"
    android:onClick = "@{() -> dashboardViewModel.onStartStopButton(context)}"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:backgroundTint="@{dashboardViewModel.isRecStarted == false ? @color/startYellow : @color/stopRed}"
    tools:backgroundTint="@color/startYellow"
    android:duplicateParentState="false"
    tools:text="START"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

What I expect to happen is that every time I press the button the function onStartStopButton(context) runs. This works fine as long as I don't rotate the device. When I rotate the device the function is run twice, if I rotate again the function is run 3 times and so on. This is not a problem if I go to another fragment and then back to the dashboard fragment. It looks like the live data observer is getting registered every time I rotate my screen, but not every time I detach and reattach the fragment.

This is true for all the elements in that fragment, whether they are data binded or I manually observe them.

Fragment code:

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        binding.dashboardViewModel = dashboardViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        
        dashboardViewModel.bleSwitchState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { switchState -> handleBleSwitch(switchState) })
        dashboardViewModel.yLims.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { yLims ->
            updatePlotWithNewData(yLims.first, yLims.second)
        })


        Timber.i("Dahsboard on create: DashboardViewModel in fragment: $dashboardViewModel")
        return root
    }
}
```

The view model:

```
class DashboardViewModel : ViewModel() {

    //region live data
    private var _isRecStarted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isRecStarted: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _isRecStarted

    //private var _bleSwitchState = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val bleSwitchState = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    private var _startStopText = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val startStopText: LiveData<String> get() = _startStopText

    private var _yLims = MutableLiveData<Pair<kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float>>()
    val yLims: LiveData<Pair<kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float>> get() = _yLims


    //endregion

    init {
        Timber.d("DashboardViewModel created!")
        bleSwitchState.value = true
    }

    //region start stop button
    fun onStartStopButton(context: Context){
        Timber.i("Start stop button pressed, recording data size: ${recordingRawData.size}, is started: ${isRecStarted.value}")
        isRecStarted.value?.let{ isRecStarted ->
            if (!isRecStarted){ // starting recording
                _isRecStarted.postValue(true)
                _startStopText.postValue(context.getString(R.string.stopBtn))
                startDurationTimer()
            }else{ // stopping recording
                _isRecStarted.postValue(false)
                _startStopText.postValue(context.getString(R.string.startBtn))
                stopDurationTimer()
            }
        } ?: run{
            Timber.e("Error! Is rec started is not there for some reason")
        }

    }
}
```

The view model is created the first time from the MainActivity as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            Timber.i("DashboardViewModel in main activity: $dashboardViewModel")
    }
}
```

**Edit** explaining why the MainActivity is tided to the ViewModel:

The reason why the ViewModel is linked to the main activity is that the main activity handles some Bluetooth stuff for a stream of data, when a new sample arrives then the logic to handle it and update the UI of the dashboard fragment is on the DashboardViewModel. The data still needs to be handled even if the dashboard fragment is not there.
So I need to pass the new sample to the DashboardViewModel from the main activity as that is where I receive it. Any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, when you instantiate the ViewModel of a Fragment with `activityViewModels`, it means that the ViewModel will follow the lifecycle of the Activity containing that Fragment. Specifically here is `MainActivity`.

**So what does ViewModel tied to Activity lifecycle mean in your case?**

When you return to the Fragment, normally LiveData (with ViewModel attached to Fragment lifcycler) will trigger again.

But when that ViewModel is attached to the Activity's lifecycle, the LiveData will not be triggered when returning to the Fragment.

That leads to when you return to the Fragment, your LiveData doesn't trigger again.

And that LiveData only triggers according to the life cycle of the activity. That is, when you rotate the screen, the Activity re-initializes, now your LiveData is triggered.

**EDIT:**

Here, I will give you one way. Maybe my code below doesn't work completely for your case, but I think it will help you in how to control LiveData and ViewModel when you bind ViewModel to Activity.

First, I recommend that each Fragment should have its own ViewModel and it should not depend on any other Fragment or Activity. Here you should rename the `DashboardViewModel` initialized by `activityViewModels()` as `ShareViewModel` or whatever you feel it is related to this being the ShareViewModel between your Activity and Fragment.

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    // Change this `DashboardViewModel` to another class name. Could be `ShareViewModel`.
    private val shareViewModel: ShareViewModel by activityViewModels()

    // This is the ViewModel attached to the DashboardFragment lifecycle.
    private val viewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels()

    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.dashboardViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

Next, when there is data triggered by the ShareViewModel's LiveData, you will set the value for the LiveData in the ViewModel associated with your Fragment. As follows:

*DashboardViewModel.kt*

```
class DashboardViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _blueToothSwitchState = MutableLiveData<YourType>()
    val blueToothSwitchState: LiveData<YourType> = _blueToothSwitchState

    private val _yLims = MutableLiveData<Pair<YourType, YourType>>()
    val yLims: LiveData<Pair<YourType, YourType>> = _blueToothSwitchState

    fun setBlueToothSwitchState(data: YourType) {
        _blueToothSwitchState.value = data
    }

    fun setYLims(data: Pair<YourType, YourType>) {
        _yLims.value = data
    }
}
```

*DashboardFragment.kt*

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        shareViewModel.run {
            bleSwitchState.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) {
                viewModel.setBlueToothSwitchState(it)
            }
            yLims.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) {
                viewModel.setYLims(it)
            }
        }

        viewModel.run {
            // Here, LiveData fires observe according to the life cycle of `DashboardFragment`. 
            // So when you go back to `DashboardFragment`, the LiveData is re-triggered and you still get the observation of that LiveData.
            blueToothSwitchState.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, ::handleBleSwitch)
            yLims.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) {
                updatePlotWithNewData(it.first, it.second)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Edit 2:**

In case you rotate the device, the Activity and Fragment will be re-initialized. At that time, LiveData will fire observe. To prevent that, use `Event`. It will keep your LiveData from observing the value until you set the value again for LiveData.

First, let's create a class `Event`.

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set

    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? = if (hasBeenHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        content
    }

    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Next, modify the return type of the LiveData that you want to trigger once.

*ShareViewModel.kt*

```
class ShareViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _test = MutableLiveData<Event<YourType>>()
    val test: LiveData<Event<YourType>> = _test

    fun setTest(value: YourType) {
        _test.value = Event(value)
    }

}
```

Add this extension to easily get LiveData's observations.

*LiveDataExt.kt*

```
fun <T> LiveData<Event<T>>.eventObserve(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: (t: T) -> Unit) {
    this.observe(owner) { it?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let(observer) }
}
```

Finally in the view, you get the data observed by LiveDatat.

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        shareViewModel.test.eventObserve(viewLifeCycleOwner) {
            Timber.d("This is test")
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

> Note: When using `LiveData` with `Event`, make sure that LiveData is not reset when rotating the device. If `LiveData` is set to value again, `LiveData` will still trigger even if you use `Event`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense. The reason why the ViewModel is linked to the main activity is that the main activity handles some Bluetooth stuff for a stream of data, when a new sample arrives then the logic to handle it and update the UI of the dashboard fragment is on the DashboardViewModel. So I need to pass the new sample to the DashboardViewModel from the main activity as that is where I receive it. Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: @FrancescoGuagliardo Wait a minute, I'm editing the comment.

Comment: @FrancescoGuagliardo I have updated the comment. Pls check it out!

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I think this will fix my issue. Before I implement it, I just wanted to ask a clarification. In the shareViewModel (linked to both main activity and fragment) do I still have LiveData for bleSwitchState and yLims (in this case), then when those change, I change the live data in the dashboard view model (not linked to the main activity)? Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. That's right. Then you will handle the case when you back to Fragment, LiveData will be triggered again. And one more thing, your current `DashboardViewModel` is equivalent to `ShareViewModel` in my case. 
Your current `DashboardViewModel` is equivalent to `ShareViewModel` in my case. So change your current `DashboardViewModel` name to something else and create a new `DashboardViewModel`.

Comment: I've implemented these changes. Now there are two view models. One is shared and the other is not. Unfortunately I still get the same problem:
`I/DashboardViewModel: Start stop button pressed, recording data size: 535, is started: true
I/chatty: uid=10261(com.example.test) identical 5 lines
I/DashboardViewModel: Start stop button pressed, recording data size: 535, is started: true`
The more I turn the phone, the more times the same function gets run when I press the button. And the view model is now only linked to the fragment. Any ideas?

Comment: @FrancescoGuagliardo I have updated the comment. Pls check it out!

Comment: Thanks for the update. This will circumvent the problem, but why is it registering one more observer every time I rotate the phone is what I don't understand.

Comment: Since it is LiveData. Like I said, every time you recreate an Activity or a Fragment, the LiveData will re-trigger the old value. That is the structure of LiveData. you can refer more here: [LiveData overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata?authuser=3)

Comment: hey @DươngMinh need help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950777/list-is-showing-incorrect-entry-using-mvvm-and-sqlite