# list is showing incorrect entry using MVVM and sqlite

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

im using sqlite with mvvm..but when i click add new and submit comming back to listing page it is not updated record in list.but when i kill app again come to list page it is showing record with duplicate entries of same record.i dont know where my code is getting wrong..plz help

**db helper:-**

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kuncorosqlite.db";

public static final String TABLE_SQLite = "sqlite";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listofMaps = new ArrayList();

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String SQL_CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SQLite + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
            " )";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SQLite);
    onCreate(db);
}

public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> getAllData() {
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> wordList;
    wordList = new MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SQLite;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(COLUMN_ID, cursor.getString(0));
            map.put(COLUMN_NAME, cursor.getString(1));
            map.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, cursor.getString(2));
            

            listofMaps.add(map);

            wordList.postValue(listofMaps);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.e("select sqlite ", "" + wordList);

    database.close();
    return wordList;
}

public void insert(String name, String address) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryValues = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_SQLite + " (name, address) " +
            "VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + address + "')";

    Log.e("insert sqlite ", "" + queryValues);
    database.execSQL(queryValues);
    database.close();
}

public void update(int id, String name, String address) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + TABLE_SQLite + " SET "
            + COLUMN_NAME + "='" + name + "', "
            + COLUMN_ADDRESS + "='" + address + "'"
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=" + "'" + id + "'";
    Log.e("update sqlite ", updateQuery);
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();
}

public void delete(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String updateQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_SQLite + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=" + "'" + id + "'";
    Log.e("update sqlite ", updateQuery);
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();
}
```

}

**viewmodel:-**

```
public class Viewmodell extends AndroidViewModel {

private DbHelper repository ;
 MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> allNotesLivedata;
public Viewmodell(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new DbHelper(application);
    allNotesLivedata = repository.getAllData();
}
void insert(String name,String Address) {
    repository.insert(name,Address);
}
void update(int id, String name, String address) {
    repository.update(id,name,address);
}
void delete(int id) {
    repository.delete(id);
}
public LiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> getAllNotes() {
    return allNotesLivedata;
}

}
```

**mainactivity (listing page):-**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
List<Data> itemList = new ArrayList<Data>();
Adapter adapter;
DbHelper SQLite = new DbHelper(this);
Viewmodell viewmodell;
public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    SQLite = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    viewmodell = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Viewmodell.class);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEdit.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String idx = itemList.get(position).getId();
            final String name = itemList.get(position).getName();
            final String address = itemList.get(position).getAddress();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsAct.class);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, idx);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    getAllData();

}

private void getAllData() {
    viewmodell.getAllNotes();
    viewmodell.allNotesLivedata.observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
            for (int i = 0; i < hashMaps.size(); i++) {
                String id = hashMaps.get(i).get(TAG_ID);
                String poster = hashMaps.get(i).get(TAG_NAME);
                String title = hashMaps.get(i).get(TAG_ADDRESS);

                Data data = new Data();

                data.setId(id);
                data.setName(poster);
                data.setAddress(title);

                itemList.add(data);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    itemList.clear();
    getAllData();
}
```

Comment: it is inside onchanged only..see properly @a_local_nobody

Comment: ahh i see, my bad

Comment: You need to debug your code in order to know what is the fault happening . There is nothing wrong with the code

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar if replace by `postvalue` by `setvalue` then duplication issue gone...but on resume the list not updating...only after killing application and then opening app then shows record in list

Comment: @a_local_nobody having issue in onResume now

Comment: This has something to do with your LiveData  . debug liveData and see whether it is returning data when your data is updated .

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar i debug this line `return allNotesLivedata;` the new record is  not returning

Comment: for example :-onresume it returning 6 record...after oncreate this livedata line returns 7 records

Comment: Viewmodel constructor is only is getting call on oncreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I see you are having problems with LiveData.

Your LiveData seems to be having problems calling `viewModel.getAllNotes()` on the `onResume()` of your activity.

With you calling `viewModel.getAllNote()`, it actually returns LiveData, you don't set the value for that LiveData. That's why when you call `viewModel.getAllNote()` the LiveData `allNotesLivedata` is not triggered.

LiveData `allNotesLivedata` only actually triggers in Constructor of `ViewModel` via `repository.getAllData()`. `repository.getAllData()` is actually where you set the value for LiveData.

Replace the function `getAllNotes()` in the ViewModel in the following way:

```
public LiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> getAllNotes() {
    return repository.getAllData();
}
```

*Edit 1:*

I am seeing you have duplicate entity. it's `onResume()` that is called multiple times in the Activity's lifecycle.

And when you call `onResume()`, you call the function `getAllData()` in `DbHelper`. You are setting the value for LiveData to `listofMap`.

I see you are not resetting the old list, and you are adding each new item received from SQLite to the old list. That results in `listofMap` consisting of old item + new item of SQLite (includes all previous record + new record). So please reset `listofMap` before adding new item from SQLite.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> getAllData() {
        ...
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            listofMap = new ArrayList();
            // Continue your code
            do {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicates entries are getting on oncreate(first time)

Comment: after adding new records when comming back to list activity the new recored is seen n also again duplicates enteries enter...now total 4 times duplicate plus one new record is seen onResume

Comment: what might be the issue? @Duong

Comment: Because you call it at `onResume()`. And in `getAllData()` function of `DbHelper`, you are saying that every time you call `getAllData()` you are adding new values ​​to `listofMaps`. You should clear `listofMaps` before adding it.

Comment: @IRONMAN I have updated the comment already.

Comment: @IRONMAN Happy to help!

Comment: hi can u help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76480901/facing-issue-while-making-dynamic-views-using-relative-layout